# Localstack AWS Lambda using container

Tags: aws-lambda, localstack

I have created a lambda function using an image/container. When I invoke the lambda I get following error. Any idea what this error means at all? I dont know what could possibly be going wrong. Please advice

```
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
INIT: Using Lambda API Runtime target host: 'amishlambda2.eu-west-1.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566'
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
INIT: Host 'amishlambda2.eu-west-1.localhost.localstack.cloud' resolves to '172.18.0.2'
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
[ERROR] [1653074544925] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to get next invocation. No Response from endpoint
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
An error occurred while attempting to execute your code.: LambdaException
2022-05-20 20:22:28
[2022/05/20/[LATEST]19f4a49620bb5a9118e1132cc7e20bd74d0e0c24cb0072837a05693ba050ca5e]
20 May 2022 19:22:24,928 [WARN] (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: None) run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed
```

Comment: Can you please share the LocalStack version (`localstack --version`) you are using and a minimal reproducible example to debug this issue? Code samples and commands would be much appreciated!